# Issues with passing value from HTML 'form' to PHP 'variable' to be used in a 'function' for greeting visitos

Tags: php, html

I have some issues with passing value from HTML "form" to PHP variable to be used in a function for greeting visitors. Here  is my code:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Please enter your name: <input class="inputbox" type="text" name="name">
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Here is my welcome.php code:

```
<?php
echo 'Thank you for entering your name!';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$inputString = $_POST['name'];}
$last_character = substr($inputString, -1 );
// echo $last_character;
if ($last_character == 'a' || $last_character == 'а'){
echo 'Здравствуйте Госпожа!'; //greeting for female visitor 
}
else {
echo 'Здравствуйте Сэр!'; //greeting for male visitor
}
?>
```

Comment: In russian, you have to wrap the person you are addressing to, into commas: `Здравствуйте, Госпожа!`

Comment: and what are those issues you're talking about?

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: Issues with utf-8 I suppose.

Comment: You are checking the same thing twice `$last_character == 'a' || $last_character == 'а'` is that a typo?

Comment: The issue is not language --i.e. Russian. As states, the value from FORM is not passed into variable and to function. I know I need to use POST ... but still not performing.

Comment: @chris85 no one is an English 'a' and the other is a Russia 'a' to catch all.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` --> `if (isset($_POST['name']))`

Comment: I have checked the code for some `utf-8` but got everything working. What problem you are getting?

Comment: @MasumNishat I tried now undoing all changes and it works. I'm not sure what was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the scope of the variable, create the variable outside of the if statement.

```
    <?php
    echo 'Thank you for entering your name!';
    $inputString  ='';
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $inputString = $_POST['name'];}
    $last_character = substr($inputString, -1 );
    // echo $last_character;
    if ($last_character == 'a' || $last_character == 'а'){
    echo 'Здравствуйте Госпожа!'; //greeting for female visitor 
    }
    else {
    echo 'Здравствуйте Сэр!'; //greeting for male visitor
    }
    ?>*
```